# PHP OOP undefined > method stdClass

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I'm new in OOP and I have 2 classes.

```
class db{
    private $_database;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_database = new PDO('mysql:host='.'localhost'.';dbname='.'lala','root','');
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public function query(){
        $query = $this->_database->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetchAll();
        return $row;
    }
}
```

first class is database.

```
class users{
    public $id, $name, $password, $mail;
    private $_databaseUSERS, $_result;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_databaseUSERS = new db();
    }

    public function nameAndpass(){
        echo "Name: {$this->name}, Password: {$this->password}".'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>';
    }

    public function get(){
        $this->_result = $this->_databaseUSERS->query();
        $object_array = array();
        foreach ($this->_result as $key => $value) {
            $object_array[] = self::blabla($value);
        }
        return $object_array;
    }

    public function blabla($record){
        foreach($record as $attribute => $value){
            $this->$attribute = $value;
        }
        return $record;
    }
}
```

and second class is users.

```
$users = new users();
$users->get();
echo $users->nameAndpass();
echo $users->mail.'<br>'
```

this is working and output is:

> Name: Johny, Password: 123456
>
> Johny@mail.com

```
$users = new users();
$user = $users->get();
foreach ($user as $userss) {
    echo $userss->name.'<br>';
}
```

this is also working and output is:

> Jack
>
> Billy
>
> Johny

```
$users = new users();
$user = $users->get();
foreach ($user as $userss) {
    echo $userss->nameAndpass().'<br>';
}
```

> this is not working and ouput is: Fatal error: Call to undefined
> method stdClass::nameAndpass() in
> C:\Users\Irakli\Desktop\Work\xamp\htdocs\index.php

How can I fix this error?

Comment: isn't it name_pass() ?

Comment: it was just typing error...
I've edited. but problem is same.

Comment: Looks like you just edited the question...and now its there..

Comment: To put it bluntly: what do you think your `blabla` function is doing? It's not really doing anything, or at least not anything sensible.

Comment: yes this wount work $user = $users->get(); returns an array of obje ct and using the data you are trying to access member function of users.

Comment: typo: $userss. Looks like it should be a user class but with the typo PHP created a stdClass.